# Print all the numbers between x & y, & find the average of these numbers

Tags: c++

So my assignment is this one: "Use a for loop to print out all the numbers (on one line, space delimited) between the 
height and width (inclusive), and then print the average (mean) of those numbers." Everything works well until I get to the very bottom, I don't know how to add up the numbers between boxWidth & boxHeight and find their average. boxWidth is my "x" so to say, and boxHeight is my "y".

```
void main() {
    int boxHeight = 0;
    int boxWidth;
    int x;
    int numOfItems;
    int sumTotal = 0;
    double average = 0;

    cout << "\tEnter a number from 3 to 10 inclusive: " << endl;
    cin >> boxHeight;
    //making a calculation for our boxHeight
    while (boxHeight < 3 || boxHeight > 10) {    
        //prompt them to try again if the number they entered isnt within the range we want.
        if (boxHeight >= 3 || boxHeight <= 10) {
            cout << "That number was not between 3 or 10 inclusive, try again: " << endl;
            cin >> boxHeight;
        }
    }

    cout << "The box's height is: " << boxHeight << endl;  
    //making a calculation for our boxWidth
    cout << "Enter a number for your box width that is greater than the height but smaller than 20:" << endl;
    cin >> boxWidth;
    while (boxWidth < boxHeight || boxWidth > 20) {
        //prompt them to try again if the number they entered isnt within the range we want.
       cout << "That number doesn't work here, try another: " << endl;
       cin >> boxWidth;
    }

    cout << "The numbers between the box's height and it's width are: " << endl;
    for (int i = boxHeight; i <= boxWidth; i++) {
         cout << i << " ";
         //this is where I'm stuck, can't add up the numbers "i" and then find their average
    }
}
```

Comment: I accidently added a useless blockqoute at the end on accident, ignore that.

Comment: [You can edit your question and fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48821017/edit).

Comment: Speaking of questions, what's yours?  `insert code here` is not going to go over well.

Comment: int sum{0};
sum += i; ????

Comment: My question is how do I add up the numbers in the for loop (int i = boxHeight; i <= boxWidth; i++) and then find the average of these numbers. This is my first time posting a question so idk if it displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add up and get the average

```
int total = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = boxHeight; i <= boxWidth; i++) {
    cout << i << " ";
    total = total + i;
    count++;
}
cout << endl;

float avg = (float)total / count;
cout << "Average is " << avg << endl;
```

Comment: Do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop to find the average at all

```
for (int i = boxHeight; i <= boxWidth; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << double(boxWidth + boxHeight) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add addidional variables, so your loop can look like that:

```
int total = 0;
int size = 0;

for (int i = boxHeight; i <= boxWidth; i++) 
{
    total += i;
    size++;
}
```

And then print average:

```
cout<<"average:"<<(float)total/size<<endl;
```

Comment: @angelorozco I don't get it, I answered the first one and someone after me, in addition looks like copied and little modified, and you marked his answer as correct. So what is sense here? Sry for comment here but can't comment on others posts yet.